# Haskell get the position of an item in a list

Tags: string, list, haskell

I'm just starting to learn Haskell and I really have a lot of questions about it. In a tutorial I'm doing I'd need to develop a functionality, in which from a list and a certain String, you will find the String's position in the list. Searching online I found this code but I really don't understand it, someone could explain it to me.

```
lookUp :: [String] -> String -> Int
lookUp [] s = error "String no encontrado"
lookUp (x:xs) s | not(x == s) = 1 + (lookUp xs s)
                | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: This looks a rather ugly way to solve it: using negative logic, `error`s, ... :(

Comment: Please ask a specific question. If every single part of this code makes no sense to you, this question is probably too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Would you understand better if it had been written as `lookup (x:xs) s = if x == s then 0 else (1 + lookup xs s)`?

Comment: Can you specify what you do not understand about it? The syntax, the types, the recursion, the pattern matching?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't elaborate further, as it was did below I was looking for someone to detail every part of the code.

Comment: @chepner i was trying your way, it gives me an error in "then 0". What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lookUp :: [String] -> String -> Int
lookUp [] s = error "..."  -- An empty list does not contain _anything_, in
                           -- particular not the string you're looking for.
lookUp (x:xs) s     -- We've eliminated the empty case, which guarantees there's
                    -- at least one (head) element in the list if we get here.
                    -- Let's examine it!
   | not (x == s) -- If the element isn't the one we were looking for...
       = 1 + (lookUp xs s)   -- then we need to continue the search, i.e. search
                             -- through the _remaining_ elements `xs` and, if `s` is
                             -- found there, report a one higher position (because
                             -- we've already skipped one element).
   | otherwise  -- Else, the element _is_ the one we were looking for...
       = 0   -- IOW, it occurs at position 0 of the (part of) the list we're
             -- currently examining.
```

Couple more remarks:

- As Willem Van Onsem commented, the `error` is a bad idea here: it is a realistic scenario that the list won't contain the element you're looking for, i.e. this is not just an “oops, a meteor strike broke the bank tresor” thing but an actual risk you should expect. But `error` will by default crash the entire program. You should instead return a `Maybe Int`, which allows you to signal a failure in a way that can easily be handled by the caller.

  ```
  lookUp :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
  lookUp [] _ = Nothing
  lookUp (x:xs) s | not(x == s)  = fmap (1 +) (lookUp xs s)
                  | otherwise    = Just 0
  ```
- Nothing in this function actually requires that it's strings that are in the list. It would work just as well with integers, single characters, booleans etc.. Anything that allows equality comparison. Thus, you might as well make the signature

  ```
  lookUp :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Maybe Int
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
lookUp :: [String] -> String -> Int
```

function lookUp accepting list of String's and String returning Int

```
lookUp [] s = error "String no encontrado"
```

if first argument is empty string return `error ...`

```
lookUp (x:xs) s | not(x == s) = 1 + (lookUp xs s)
                | otherwise = 0
```

interesting part `(x:xs)` get first string from list, and string 
`|` is guard, so if string in `x` isnt equal with `s` string `return 1 + ( lookup xs s)` .. ==> recursive call `lookUp` with `xs` - list of strings without compared string `x` and string `s` as parameter

in the end `othervise` returns 0

manually:

`lookUp [] "foo"` ==> first pattern [] so returns error

`lookUp ["foo"] "foo"` ==> second pattern and runs guard ==> `not( "foo" == "foo") = 1 + ( lookUp [] "foo")` , this ends in second line `othervise 0` so it return correct location `0`

`lookUp [ "bar", "foa", "foo", "fao" ] "foo"` ==> second pattern and expands to: `not ( "bar" == "foo") return 1 + (lookUp ["foa", "foo", "fao"] "foo")` then `not( "bar" == "foo") return 1 + (not ("foa" == "foo") = return 1 + (lookUp ["foo", "fao"] "foo"))` then not( "bar" == "foo") return 1 + (not ("foa" == "foo") = return 1 + (not("foo" == "foo") = return 1 )`.. but because now test is *True* uses`othervise = 0`so`1+1 = 2`and`2` is correct string location in list.

and last possibility:

`lookUp ["bar"] "foo"` ==>  `not("bar" == "foo") = return 1 + (lookUp [] "foo")` and `lookUp` with empty list throws error